# Angular TypeScript error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: angular, typescript

what is wrong with the following code.
it complains that the void is not assignable to boolean for const invalidResult.

```
isSubmitDisabled(): boolean {

    const results: Result[] = this.getLFResults();

    const invalidResult: boolean = results.forEach(function(result) {
        if (result.indicators.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    return results.length === 0 || invalidResult;
    // return results.length === 0;
}

getLFResults(): Result[] {

    if (!this.logframe) {
        const results: Result[] = [];
        this.store.select(getCurrentLogFrameState)
            .map((logframe) => {
                this.logframe = logframe;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return results;
            });
        if (this.logframe !== null && this.logframe !== undefined) {
            return this.logframe.results;
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return a value, the [signature of the method](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1215) is:

```
forEach(callbackfn: (this: void, value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void): void;
```

You probably want to use the [every method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which returns a boolean:

```
results.every(function (result) {
    if (result.indicators.length === 0) {
        return true;
        }
    return false;
});
```

Or the [some method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example):

```
results.some(function (result) {
    if (result.indicators.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control) does not return anything. You are probably looking for [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control) which will return a `boolean` if any of the items satisfy the confition:

```
const invalidResult: boolean = results.some(function (result) {
    return result.indicators.length === 0;
});
```